# Rvm version error

Tags: ruby, rvm

I have installed many flavors of ruby on rvm, and using following command to change rvm ruby versions.

```
rvm use 1.9.3
```

then `ruby -v` gives me following result

```
ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13 revision 48407) [i686-linux]
```

but when i try to run any commands like `rails s` or `bundle install`
it gives me following error

```
Your Ruby version is 2.3.1, but your Gemfile specified 1.9.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's can happens, when you trying to use fresh installed `ruby` without `bundler`, all newest installed `ruby` should also include `bundler` installation.

```
$> rvm use 1.9.3 && gem install bundler # may terminal reload needed
$> bundle install
$> bundle exec rails s
```

Answer (score 2):

Using

> rvm list

you can get list of ruby version on your system along with current & default versions.

If ruby version is not specified in Gemfile, then it is generally considering default rvm version.

But if it is specified in Gemfile, then that version of ruby should be installed in your system along with its bundler.

First make sure ruby version either installing or using it,

```
rvm install '1.9.3'

rvm use '1.9.3'
```

To install bundle of required ruby version, run this command

```
gem install bundler
```